# Weblogic URI case sensitivity

Tags: apache, weblogic, case-sensitive, weblogic-10.x

We are trying to put a 6 servered cluster environment in weblogic with Apache as a web server.

When accessing the URLs with multiple URI cases (abc/Abc/ABC or servelet/Servelet etc.. ), we are getting 404 error but if we change to proper case in the URL, it works.

Is there any case sensitivity seeting which can be done in weblogic?

We have enabled case sensitivity ignore option in apache, but still no luck.

Any ideas?

Regards,
Raja.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context root will always be case sensitive in WebLogic. However, you can use rewrite rules in your Apache configuration to change the incoming request to match the case of your URLs in WebLogic.